# Newton's method is divergent for some polynomials

Tags: c++, polynomial-math, newtons-method, convergence

I've tried to implement Newton's method for polynomials. Like:

```
double xn=x0;
double gxn=g(w, n, xn);

int i=0;
while(abs(gxn)>e && i<100){
    xn=xn-(gxn/dg(w, n, xn));
    gxn=g(w, n, xn);

    i++;
}
```

where `g(w, n, xn)` computes the value of the function and `dg(w, n, xn)` computes the derivative.

As `x0` I use starting point `M` which I found using Sturm's theorem.

My problem is that this method is divergent for some polynomials like `x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1`. Maybe it's not regular, but I noticed that it happens when the solution of the equation is a negative number. Where can I look for an explanation?

Edit:
dg

```
double result=0;
for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++)
    result+=w[i]*(n-i)*pow(x, n-i-1);
```

where n is the degree of polynomial

Comment: The set of starting values that converge to a particular root is called a basin of attraction. If you google that you'll discover that the maths is very advanced.

Comment: [Are you surprised?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal)

Comment: @PaulBoddington It appears that the OP had actually a bug (or more) in their code rather than a starting value outside the basin of attraction. However, it appears that the OP assumes that Raphson's method (falsely called Newton's -- who failed to publish it) should always converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why would you say it's divergent.

I implemented Newton's method similarly to yours:

```
double g(int w[], int n, double x) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
        result += w[i] * pow(x, n - i);
    return result;
}

double dg_dx(int w[], int n, double x) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        result += w[i] * (n - i) * pow(x, n - i - 1);
    return result;
}

int main() {

    double xn = 0;        // Choose initial value. I chose 0.
    double gx;
    double dg_dx_x;
    int w[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
    int i = 0;
    int n = 4;

    do {
        gx = g(w, n, xn);
        dg_dx_x = dg_dx(w, n, xn);
        xn = xn - (gx / dg_dx_x);
        i++;
    } while (abs(gx) > 10e-5 && i < 100);

    std::cout << xn << '\n';
}
```

And it yields `-0.997576`, which is close to the solution `-1`.

Comment: hmm, my programm should be flexible for any polynomial,  I wrote g and dg, so maybe it causes the problem. Could you look at it?

Comment: What did you mean by the variables `w` and `n` in your functions `g` and `dg`? What is the full definition of `g` and `dg`? This should not be a problem if `g` and `dg` are correctly defined, therefore you should post your implementation and this way we could see what went wrong.

Comment: w is the array of coefficients of polynomial and n is the degree. I've just updated my post of dg definition

Comment: I wonder if I rather should have used Horner's to compute g and dg ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to make the program fit all polynomials using w[] and n. It works fine. The main difference, and I guess this was your issue, is that in the derivative function, which I called `dg_dx`, the stopping condition in the `for` loop should be `i < n`, since the derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: Actually... Thank you so much

Comment: That depends on how you encoded the polynomial. Hopefully with a `double` array for `w` and `n=sizeof(w)/sizeof(w[0]) - 1`. Then the code above converges directly to -1.